# Remove active directory certificate service role - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the following setup

1. First DC1 - with AD DS and AD certificate services.
2. Second DC2 - with AD, recently dcpromoted.

I've never used AD CS in domain environement.

I need to reinstall DC1, but cant demote it, because AD Certificated Services role is installed on it. How to plan and perform reinstalation of DC1 ? What will happen when I will remove that AD DS, Can i simply remove AD CS, demote, reinstall DC1, and perform dcpromo ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not depend on certificates issued from DC1 (or if DC1 has never issued any certificates), you can safely remove the AD CS role, demote and remove the machine and the reinstall.

Be sure to transfer all FSMO roles to DC2.

Comment: ...and it's not advised to have AD CS on the same machine as your domain controller either, for what that's worth.  So, if you need that role, this time around, put it on its own server.

Comment: Unfortunately DC2 has a certificates issued from DC1.
I want to add DC3, and dcpromo it while DC1(ADCS) is offline. Is that safe? I'm trying to find a way to ged rid of ADCS from this particular environment.